# Am I able to track the executed Java scripts in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a page taken from ThemeForest and I try to examine how it works. If I press one of the links the action taking by the browser is different to one if I just use the anchor link. So I suppose that there is some script run and make the page change more beautiful.
The problem is that I can not understand which script is running in this case: the link has no 'id' tag.
So how do I track the script running upon the link click?

Comment: See this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8018448/1773904

Comment: OK, @Clark, I did this and I can see the event ('Event(Click)'), Function Call x 2, Function Call, Function Call (jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3) and some Timer manipulations... But WHICH functions was called is not clear. If I click on the row 'Function Call x 2' for example I will see only the information about execution time and  CPU time, but no reference to the function name. Am I did something wrong?

Comment: When you select a DOM element in dev tools, you have a panel to the right with several sections. One of them is `Event Listeners`. This is the place where you can find which JavaScript handlers are bound to the element. Also you may be interested in setting `DOM breakpoint` on this element.